# How big Eclipse Java heap space is need for mymap = new int[500000][500000]; without OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, memory

Or I ask the question in different way:  Given 64GB physical memory, how big 2D integer array can be used in Java Eclipse?  int[120000][120000] roughly without error?

Thanks!

Comment: The 2D array in the title is a terabyte (1000 GB). You aren't going to be able to create that on anything short of a super computer.

Answer (score 1):

Java int values are 4 bytes each. The array in your question is `120,000^2 * 4` bytes, or `120,000^2 * 4 / 1024^2` GB, which is about 59GB, which is approaching the end of your memory availability. Realistically, you're going to need some extra memory available for hosting the OS itself, the Java application, etc.

Though, I really do question the need for creating such a large amount of data in a single array. Does all of this really need to be in memory at once? Would it be better to restructure so you need only a subset of data in memory at once?

Comment: Thanks Andrew!   My java code uses a for loop which has 500,000 iterations.  The execution is forever!   That is the reason I am trying to use a 2D array to replace current algorithm.    Well, I need to find another approach for the issue:  given n points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), ...... There is a S by S square.  What is the maximum number of the given points which located within that square?     n is 500,000.